# Midnight commander: How to define condition in mc.menu

Tags: mc

I'm trying to add new command, and the menu option should  be displayed when the single file is selected, (it's executable and not a directory) or (not a link and the name ends with .so) or (not a link and the name contains .so.). The following condition does not work at all: `+ ! t t & ((t x & t n) | (t r & f \.so$) | (t r & f \.so.))`

Also, do I need to use brackets e.g. c1 & c2 | c3 & c4 instead of (c1 & c2) | (c3 & c4)??